# how to change background images with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

so far (with the help of this comm :)) I created a full viewport background, thats able to switch on click.

Since I'm a beginner I  have two questions:

1) Is the code "good", or did I wrote it to complicated?

and the Mainquestion:

How can I put a fade effect into my code? Now it's kinda ugly, because the images are loading slow (stuttering). I imagine something like this:

**Image--Click--Fading black--Fading in new Image--Click--Fading black---Fading in new Image--..**

Here is the code I wrote:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="t1">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.t1 {
    background: url(pics/homescreen.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    var y = 1;
    $('.t1').click(function () {
        var x = ['url(pics/screen1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
            'url(pics/screen2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
            'url(pics/schild.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed'
        ]
        $('.t1').css('background', x[y]);
        $('.t1').css('background-size', 'cover');
        if (y == 2) {
            y = 0;
        } else {
            y = y + 1;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: working fiddle with OP code http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/FNUx8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bSAm2/
This doesn't include preloading, but the effect is quite nice.
If you are interested in a preloader, you probably want to preload images one at a time, when they are needed: **loading all images upfront or worse in the head of your document, will likely slow down page loading beyond what's an acceptable UX.
Also, transition won't work on older browsers (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp))**

To animate CSS properties, you can use http://api.jquery.com/animate/
In particular, you can fade out the current image by animating its opacity (to 0), then, when this animation is completed change the image source (while it is not visible) and start the fade-in animation.

For best appearance, you can preload images "Just in Time", for example you can preload the next image to show, so there won't be any latency

**EDIT**

This example works, and uses closure so that you can have multiple images rotating independently:

```
$(function () {

var images = ['url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-8.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
            'url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
            'url(http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-9.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed'
        ];
function bindSwitcher (elem) {
    var imageIndex = 0;
    return function switchImage () {
        elem.fadeOut(function (){
            elem.css('background', images[imageIndex]);
            if (imageIndex == images.length - 1) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            } else {
                imageIndex += 1;
            }            
            elem.css('background-size', 'cover');
            elem.fadeIn();
        });
       };
}

var imageSwitcher = bindSwitcher($('#t1'));
$('#t1').click(imageSwitcher);
$('#t2').click(bindSwitcher($('#t2')));
});
```

And the HTML, with a little change to show the difference:

```
<div id="t1" class="t1" style="position: absolute; left:0%">
</div>
<div id="t2" class="t1" style="position: absolute; left:50%">
</div>
```

Comment: thx this helped a lot. Now I'm trying to understand what exactly is going on your code :). 2 Questions so far: How can I change the fade color to black (actually it's white)? I tried to change background to black (in css), but that didn't helped. And how can I set the fadeOut time (the fadeIn could I changed by elem.fadeIn(4000); but at elem.fadeOut where do I put the number)?

Comment: Hi, glad it helped!
For the black background, your solution didn't work because you are making the div fade out, so even if you color it black, it won't be shown.
One solution could be putting a black div, with the exact size of the images, right behind it, so when the images fade out, this div will be shown (z-index and position attributes in css will help in this direction).

Comment: For your second question, you can use [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) as a reference: 

Basically, instead of passing a callback to fadeOut, you'll pass it an object with a field named `"done"` for the callback, and another field `"duration"` for the duration of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/FNUx8/8/***

> Is the code "good", or did I wrote it to complicated?

A couple of things which you could do is:

1. Take your image array outside of `click` handler. You woudn't want to create that array every time a click happens.
2. Reduce the code to cycle the array by using a modulus.
3. Refer to the element using `this`.
4. Use an `id` instead of `class` to target the element directly if that is unique.

So, effectively your code reduces to:

```
var x = ['url(...1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
        'url(...2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
        'url(..3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed'
];
var index = 0;

$('#t1').click(function () {
    index = (index + 1) % x.length;
    $(this).css('background', x[index]);
});
```

> How can I put a fade effect into my code? Now it's kinda ugly, because
>   the images are loading slow (stuttering)

(1.) You can put a fade effect using CSS3 `transition`:

```
#t1 {
    ...
    transition: 1s;
}
```

(2.) There is stuttering because the images are loaded at runtime. You could avoid that by pre-loading images:

One way could be like this:

```
var d = []; // create an array for holding dummy elements

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    d[i] = $("<img>"); // create an img and add to the array
    d[i].attr('src', x[i]).hide(); // add src to img and hide it
    $("body").append(d[i]); // add the img to body to start load
}
```

Ideally wrap this code in the `head` so that this is done by the time DOM is ready. Put rest of your code either wrapped in `body` at the end or in `.ready`.

**Edit:**

Changed the preloading code to use `img`. Updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not complicated, in time you'll learn to write cleaner (good) code. Here is my suggestions:
1. move the `x` definition outside the click event, put it right after `y` and `y` should be 0 initially;
2. `if(y == 2)` is too static, beter take the length of the array `if(y == x.length)`; 
3. remove `background-size` from script, it's set in css; 
4. For fade effect you can do something like this:

```
$('.t1').fadeOut(300, function() {
   $(this).css('background', x[y]).fadeIn(300);
});
```

I haven't tested it, but should do the job.

Comment: thx so far. To 3.) I now what you meant with that, but if I remove the codeline in jQuery it doens't work. To 4.) the fade is doing something really wird :D

Comment: I played with this code a bit, here is what I came up http://jsfiddle.net/FNUx8/5/